# Update-spsolution keep old version

Tags: sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, solution-deployment, gac

In Sharepoint Foundation 2013 i have developped an spsolution scoped web with an eventreceiver. It's attached to a specific list in featureactivated.
When i do

```
update-spsolution -identity xxx.wsp -literalpath xxx -GACDeployment
```

It's correctly deployed but change like adding simple log are not visible. It seems keeping old version.
I looked in GAC the dll version and it's the correct one.

I tryied to remove and reinstall without success

```
unistall-spsolution
remove-spsolution
add-spsolution
install-spsolution
```

i deleted dll in temp folder too

I'm really disapointed because i have no more idea to find a solution.

Answer (score 2):

We had this issue in recent past, for us this dll stuck in timer service cache. I would do the following things:

- Restart the SharePoint timer and Admin service on all server in the farm
- Reset IIS on all servers